# UITableview Segue

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue

I am developing a simple UITableview app. The 1st page is a collapsable UITableView.

[UITableView Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdmoW.png)

Here is the basic code for the sections:

```
var sections = [

    Section(sec: "One",
            subSec: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
            expanded: false),

    Section(sec: "Two",
            subSec: ["F", "G", "H", "I", "J"],
            expanded: false),

    Section(sec: "Three",
            subSec: ["K", "L", "M", "N", "O"],
            expanded: false),
```

The struct for Section has been set in a separate file:

```
struct Section {
var sec: String!
var subSec: [String]! // [ ] = Array of Strings
var expanded: Bool!

init(sec: String, subSec: [String], expanded: Bool) {
    self.sec = sec
    self.subSec = subSec
    self.expanded = expanded
}
}
```

I don't seem to be able to get the tableview sub sections to segue to a new view controller and pass the data i.e the selected letter.

What I want to achieve is to have a user select a subSec letter from a section and have that segue to a new screen with a set of data related to that letter, perhaps from a dictionary.

Main view controller:

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, ExpandableHeaderViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var sections = [

        Section(sec: "One",
                subSec: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
                expanded: false),

        Section(sec: "Two",
                subSec: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
                expanded: false),

        Section(sec: "Three",
                subSec: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
                expanded: false),


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sections[section].subSec.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 44
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        if (sections[indexPath.section].expanded) {
            return 44
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let header = ExpandableHeaderView()
        header.customInit(title: sections[section].sec, section: section, delegate: self)
        return header
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "labelCell")!
        cell.textLabel?.text = sections[indexPath.section].subSec[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func toggleSection(header: ExpandableHeaderView, section: Int) {
        sections[section].expanded = !sections[section].expanded

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        for i in 0 ..< sections[section].subSec.count {
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: i, section: section)], with: .automatic)
        }
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }


}
```

Comment: Where is the code for `didSelect`? Where is the `prepareForSegue()` code? With this `sections[indexPath.section].subSec[indexPath.row]`  you should have the letter, no?

Comment: I will give this a try, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Subsection \(indexPath.row) in section \(indexPath.section) selected!")
}
```

Comment: This works great and shows which section was tapped in the console.

Comment: I'm glad it worked how you wanted :) if you have typing suggestions, it can be interesting just typing 'override func tableView' and looking at all the options...